# What's the default number of clients camel application can handle

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a spring boot application that uses cxf camel routes, I didn't do any special configurations, entry point is http://0.0.0.0. My question is what is the maximum number of clients that my application is able to handle concurrently without any customizations? And what should I do and where if for example the defaults are insufficient?

Answer (score 0):

It s about your web server. if you are use quarkus + camel  quarkus use vert.x in background. you must configure vert.x and this parameters are  vertx.eventloops.poolsize and vert.worker thread size. if you are use quarkus+spring boot. spring boot uses tomcat in default . u can use undertow or jetty.its tomcat parameters

```
server:
  tomcat:
    threads:
      max: 300
      min-spare: 60
```